# Cast an IList to an IList<t> using dynamic instantiation

Tags: nhibernate, casting, ilist

I am try to convert the following NHibernate query using dyanmic instantiation into an IList<t> rather than an IList.

```
IList<AllName> allNames =
  (IList<AllName>)Session.CreateQuery(
  @"select new AllName(
  name.NameId, name.FirstName, origin.OriginId, origin.Description,
  name.Sex, name.Description, name.SoundEx
  ) from Name name join name.Origin origin")
  .SetFirstResult(skip)
  .SetMaxResults(pageSize);
```

Running this I get the following error:-

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'NHibernate.Impl.QueryImpl' to type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.IList`1[Domain.Model.Entities.AllName]'.

I know that I can return

```
IList results = Sesssion.CreateQuery(...
```

but my service layers expect an

```
IList<AllName>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option would be to write an `IList<T>` implementation which proxies to an `IList`, casting where appropriate. It shouldn't be too hard to do, albeit somewhat tedious. LINQ will make this slightly easier in terms of implementing `IEnumerable<T>` etc - you can just call the underlying iterator and call `Cast<T>()` on it, for example.

Another solution would be to create a new `List<T>` from the returned list:

```
IList query = Session.CreateQuery(...);
IList<AllName> allNames = new List<AllName>(query.Cast<AllName>());
```

EDIT: As Sander so rightly points out, this is what `ToList` is for:

```
IList query = Session.CreateQuery(...);
return query.Cast<AllName>().ToList();
```

EDIT: All of this has been NHibernate-agnostic, as it were - I don't actually know much about NHibernate. Rippo has now found a much simpler answer - call `List<AllName>` instead (which is an NHibernate method).

Comment: When you're using the `.Cast<T>()` extension method, you can just as well add an `.ToList()`.

Comment: Thanks Jon, the cast worked. Is there any kind of performance hit here? My page size is set to 50 records so I am not returning an enormous amount of data.

Comment: @sander: doh! Why didn't. I think of that? :)

Comment: Jon, found another way, just posting in case anyone else looks at this post. I can simply do  **return query.List<AllName>();**

Comment: @Rippo: That's where my lack of knowledge of NHibernate has let me down :) I'll edit it into the answer just to make it more visible.