# NHibernate List - Unable to cast object of type System.Collections.Hashtable

Tags: c#, linq, nhibernate, casting

I'm trying to accomplish the same thing as described in this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1977295/cast-an-ilist-to-an-ilistt-using-dynamic-instantiation). However the solutions mentioned in the responses don't resolve my issue.

The API exposed to me is using the following for example, shortened for ex purpsoes

```cs
IList results = CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec myStoredProc ...")
  .SetParameters("..", ...)
  .SetResultTransformer(new NHibernate.Transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer())
  .List();
```

I however need this to be a specific object of type T that is a custom object. I tried changing this to use NHibernate **List T()** but no luck there either.

If I try to cast this I'm usually seeing an error message that states **Unable to case object of type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' to type '...'**

Has anyone encountered similiar problem and know how to cast/convert this to a different type than System.Collections.Hashtable. My main goal is I need to use LINQ statements to query the results and can't do that with an IList that he code returns.

I'm attempting to just use the API as is and not change because this is already used in other places in consuming apps. So if there is a way to work with IList and cast/convert it that is best. I understand that this may be occurring due to use of the NHibernate.Transform.AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer.

Thanks for any insight. I've Googled and searched SO for this and not finding an answer as of yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution here should not be so complicated. In case, that your entity looks like:

```
public class MyEntity 
{
    public virtual int    Property1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property2 { get; set; }
    ...
```

And the result of the stored procedure is like:

```
SELECT col1 as Property1 // the same alias as property name is crucial
     , col2 as Property2
     ...
```

We can profit from the built-in `AliasToBean<TEntity>()` transformer:

```
IList<MyEntity> results = CurrentSession.CreateSQLQuery("exec myStoredProc ...")
  .SetParameters("..", ...)
  .SetResultTransformer(NHibernate.Transform.Transformers.AliasToBean<MyEntity>())
  .List<MyEntity>();
```

Comment: I had not heard AliasToBean in quite some time, thanks. Jimmy Board also mentioned it in an article on [Ad-hoc Mapping with NHibernate](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/06/30/ad-hoc-mapping-with-nhibernate/). Thanks for the response.